# Woocommerce Email Notification to Different Email address in Shipping Field

Tags: notifications, woocommerce

I trying to achieve like below.

I want to send a woocommerce product as a gift to my friend or brother or like that. To accomplish this I am going to depend on "Ship to different Address" Field in checkout page. So If anyone want to send that product as a gift then he or she can send the product to a different shipping address which is the gift receiver address.

For this I have modified the checkout page to add a email field to the section of   "Ship to different Address" .

Now what I want is that I want to send a email notification about the order to the gift receiver also so that the receiver knows that someone has gifted him this product..

How can I send the email notification about the order to the gift receiver email address ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I don't need it anymore to be done. But I think this plugin http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-checkout-field-editor/11725925 will do all for you in checkout field that you want to do. This is what I needed.

Thanks for the effort everybody

Comment: I don't think that plugin will send the email notifications to the newly added email field. At least it isn't mentioned anywhere in the sales text. So it is kind of poor form to mark this as the answer when it isn't confirmed to solve the question as written.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plugin I've written to add a shipping emails. It should work, but I wrote it a while ago so no guarantees.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WooCommerce Shipping Email
Plugin URI: http://www.kathyisawesome.com/
Description: Add a shipping email field to checkout and notify of new orders
Version: 1.0
Author: Kathy Darling
Author URI: http://kathyisawesome.com
Requires at least: 4.0
Tested up to: 4.0

Copyright: © 2014 Kathy Darling.
License: GNU General Public License v3.0
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html

*/


/**
 * The Main WC_Shipping_Email class
 **/
if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Shipping_Email' ) ) :

class WC_Shipping_Email {

    /**
     * @var WC_Shipping_Email - the single instance of the class
     * @since 1.0
     */
    protected static $_instance = null;           

    /**
     * Main WC_Shipping_Email Instance
     *
     * Ensures only one instance of WC_Shipping_Email is loaded or can be loaded.
     *
     * @static
     * @see WC_Shipping_Email()
     * @return WC_Shipping_Email - Main instance
     * @since 1.0
     */
    public static function instance() {
        if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) ) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    /**
     * Cloning is forbidden.
     *
     * @since 1.0
     */
    public function __clone() {
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'Cheatin&#8217; huh?', 'woocommerce-mix-and-match' ), '2.0' );
    }

    /**
     * Unserializing instances of this class is forbidden.
     *
     * @since 1.0
     */
    public function __wakeup() {
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'Cheatin&#8217; huh?', 'mix-and-match' ), '2.0' );
    }

    /**
     * WC_Shipping_Email Constructor
     *
     * @access public
     * @return WC_Shipping_Email
     * @since 1.0
     */

    public function __construct() { 

        $this->id = 'email';
        $this->meta = '_shipping_email';
        $this->label = __( 'Shipping Email', 'woocommerce-shipping-email' );

        // add email field to checkout
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields' , array( $this, 'add_shipping_fields' ) );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields' , array( $this, 'admin_shipping_fields' ) );

        // add recipient to specific emails
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order' , array( $this, 'add_recipient' ), 20, 2 );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order' , array( $this, 'add_recipient' ), 20, 2 );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_note' , array( $this, 'add_recipient' ), 20, 2 );

        // display meta key in order overview
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_customer_details' , array( $this, 'after_customer_details' ) );

        // display meta key in email
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_template_part' , array( $this, 'before_email_addresses' ), 10, 4 );

    }


    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Plugin Functions */
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    /**
     * Add email to front-end shipping fields
     *
     * @var  array $fields
     * @return  array
     * @since 1.0
     */

    function add_shipping_fields( $fields ) {
        $fields['shipping_' . $this->id] = array(
            'label'         => $this->label,
            'required'      => true,
            'class'         => array( 'form-row-first' ),
            'validate'      => array( 'email' ),
        );
        return $fields;
    }

    /**
     * Add email to Admin Order overview
     *
     * @var  array $fields
     * @return  array
     * @since 1.0
     */

    function admin_shipping_fields( $fields ) {
        $fields[$this->id] = array(
            'label'         => $this->label
        );
        return $fields;
    }

    /**
     * Add recipient to emails
     *
     * @var  mixed $email
     * @return  mixed
     * @since 1.0
     */
    function add_recipient( $email, $order ) {
        $additional_email = get_post_meta( $order->id, $this->meta, true );
        if( $additional_email && is_email( $additional_email )){
            $email = explode( ',', $email );
            array_push( $email, $additional_email );
        }
        return $email;
    }

    /**
     * Display meta in my-account area Order overview
     *
     * @var  object $order
     * @return  null
     * @since 1.0
     */

    public function after_customer_details( $order ){

        $value = get_post_meta( $order->id, $this->meta, true );

        if( $value ){
            echo '<dt>' . $this->label . ':</dt><dd>' . $value . '</dd>';
        }

    }

    /**
     * Display meta in my-account area Order overview
     *
     * @var  array $fields
     * @return  array
     * @since 1.0
     */

    public function before_email_addresses( $template_name, $template_path, $located, $args ){

        if( $template_name == 'emails/email-addresses.php' && isset( $args['order' ] ) && ( $value = get_post_meta( $args['order']->id, $this->meta, true ) ) ){ 

            if ( isset( $args['plain_text'] ) && $args['plain_text'] ){

                echo $this->label . ': ' . $value . "\n";

            } else {

                echo '<p><strong>' . $this->label . ':</strong> ' . $value . '</p>';

            }

        }

    }



} //end class: do not remove or there will be no more guacamole for you

endif; // end class_exists check


/**
 * Returns the main instance of WC_Shipping_Email to prevent the need to use globals.
 *
 * @since  2.0
 * @return WooCommerce
 */
function WC_Shipping_Email() {
  return WC_Shipping_Email::instance();
}

// Launch the whole plugin
WC_Shipping_Email();
```

Here is the result in the checkout page, you can see that the Shipping Email field is added under the "ship to a different address" column.

[image: Result in Twenty Sixteen]

Comment: I need this email field in "Ship to Different Address Form" . Please check this screenshot http://prntscr.com/9fqutp and comment in the screenshot

Comment: I don't understand your comment. In my screenshot you can see that the Shipping Email field is added under the "ship to a different address" column. And it should email an order notification to that email. What's the problem?

Comment: Actually I don't need this to be done anymore so I am leaving it. But for your understanding I want a second email address where the order notification can be sent along with the main notification

Comment: Umm, that's exactly what I provided in the code. It adds an extra field in the shipping address area and then sends certain emails to that address. Did you try this code at all?

Comment: I tried your code but it sends notification only to the billing email.

Comment: I re-tested this and confirm that it does send emails to the shipping email on all core customer emails: processing order, completed order, and customer note. It does not auto-enable sending to a secondary email for every email. Each email must be enabled individually. See the `woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order` filter in my code as an example.

Comment: I didn't check your code.. But after activation I tested it and it doesn't send email to secondary email... Probably my settings is not right..

Comment: Very interesting Unfortunately, i'll try but my website was immediatly broken (error 500)..

Comment: @angelilo_This code is 2.5 years old. It's WC2.6.x compatible, but needs to be updated for WC3+.